# What is the exact difference between OnKeyListener and OnEditorActionListener?

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I have read that `OnKeyListener` is for detecting hard keys and `OnEditorActionListener` for soft keys. However, there are many examples in the internet, therefore it seems that they both work OK in any situation.

I have tried both and `OnKeyListener` works **only on real device** while `OnEditorActionListener` works on **real device and emulator** too.

Because of this, I want to know the difference between them and to figure out when to use either of them. I would appreciate if anyone could explain me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a small copy paste from the docs:

```
 /**
     * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a hardware key event is
     * dispatched to this view. The callback will be invoked before the key event is
     * given to the view. This is only useful for hardware keyboards; a software input
     * method has no obligation to trigger this listener.
     */
    public interface OnKeyListener {
        /**
         * Called when a hardware key is dispatched to a view. This allows listeners to
         * get a chance to respond before the target view.
         * <p>Key presses in software keyboards will generally NOT trigger this method,
         * although some may elect to do so in some situations. Do not assume a
         * software input method has to be key-based; even if it is, it may use key presses
         * in a different way than you expect, so there is no way to reliably catch soft
         * input key presses.
         *
         * @param v The view the key has been dispatched to.
         * @param keyCode The code for the physical key that was pressed
         * @param event The KeyEvent object containing full information about
         *        the event.
         * @return True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.
         */
        boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
    }
```

> Do not assume a software input method has to be key-based; even if it
>   is, it may use key presses in a different way than you expect, so
>   there is no way to reliably catch soft input key presses.

Similarly,

```
   /**
     * Set a special listener to be called when an action is performed
     * on the text view.  This will be called when the enter key is pressed,
     * or when an action supplied to the IME is selected by the user.  Setting
     * this means that the normal hard key event will not insert a newline
     * into the text view, even if it is multi-line; holding down the ALT
     * modifier will, however, allow the user to insert a newline character.
     */
    public void setOnEditorActionListener(OnEditorActionListener l) {
        createEditorIfNeeded();
        mEditor.createInputContentTypeIfNeeded();
        mEditor.mInputContentType.onEditorActionListener = l;
    }
```

Comment: So, it means that `OnEditorActionListener` is preferred over `OnKeyListener ` ? Because, last one might not get triggered in some cases?